# how to send an array to a procedure

Tags: arrays, assembly, procedure, x86-16

Hi I'm doing DES in assembler 8086 and I have a lot of arrays, also I need some procedures but I don't know how send an array to a procedure.I tried using the stack but it didn't worked. Can you give me a hand? I'm using TASM

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Say you have an array of words defined as:

```
myArray dw 10, 9, 8, 7, 6, 5, 4, 3, 2, 1
numItems dw 10
```

And you want to pass that to a procedure:

```
push myArray  ; the address of the array
mov ax, [numItems]
push ax       ; the length of the array
call myProc
; if you want the caller to clean up ...
add sp, 4  ; adjust sp to get rid of params
```

Then myProc would be:

```
myProc:
    mov bp, sp ; save stack pointer
    mov cx, [bp+4] ; cx gets the number of items
    mov bx, [bp+6] ; bx gets the address of the array
    ; at this point, you can address the array through [bx]
    mov ax, [bx+0} ; first element of the array
    mov ax, [bx+2] ; second element of the array
    ret 4  ; cleans up the stack, removing the two words you'd pushed onto it
    ; or, if you want the caller to clean up ...
    ret
```

Comment: ok that´s useful, thanks. But what about if i have two different arrays and i need move values form one of them too another and I need different index every time I move a value?? For example first move the value in position 5 then value in position 20. How can I do that?? I just found something like this

Comment: @AlvaroFallas: I suggest you find a good assembly language tutorial. The Art of Assembly Language is well regarded. http://www.planetpdf.com/codecuts/pdfs/aoa.pdf

Comment: Im sorry as I was saying I did something like this in order to get a value from different positions mov ax,byte ptr DS:[[bp+6]+(bx*2)] bp+6 is the address of the array i need bx*2 is my position. But a get a error message "Ilegal indexing mode"

Comment: You're trying to move a byte into AX? If you want to move a byte, you have to move it into AL. Try `mov al, byte ptr DS:[bp+6+bx*2]`. Or, if you want to move into AX, you can use the `movzx` instruction. Although that's not an 8086 instruction. I think it appeared with the '386.